# Left align Page Viewer WebPart

Tags: iframe, page-viewer-web-part

How can I left align a Page Viwer WebPart, i.e. the iframe within?
All my included pages are centered.

Answer (score 0):

using developer tool bar you can grab the ID of the iframe and then using CSS you can left align it...

Comment: I already tried to do that, but it didn't work. Which CSS command would you use?